# Verify user using digits

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am using Fabric digits to verify user for my app.
I have done everything as told in Description but when verifying user i get

**HTTP Error: 401 Authorization Required, API Error: 32, User Message: Try Again**

Here is my code please help

```
phoneButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
    phoneButton.setAuthTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    phoneButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession digitsSession, String phoneNumber) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException e) {

        }
    });
```

This error i don't know what i am doing wrong pleas help i have been stuck on this for more than 2 days.

Please help.

I tested this on several devices with different network operator.
It works on only one. Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I have the same problem. do you allready have a solution?

Comment: Couldnt find Solution to it looks like its not available for some networks. It worked on few

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this
Add this line of code under your OnCreate method.

```
Digits.clearActiveSession();
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Digits.Builder digitsBuilder = new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme);
```

Comment: When ever you post any code, please make sure that you have applied the appropriate formatting. You may read more here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks